# Sorting and simplifying the content of a data frame in R

Tags: r

So I have a table with `Names`, `Date of Birth`, and `Districts`. My districts range from `1010` to `1239`. What I want is to simplify the districts --> make `1010:1019` be `1`, `1020:1029` be `2` etc. I can do this by subtracting data, and building new vectors, but I wish to still have just one data frame.

Could someone tell me how I do this in R?

Comment: Next time, please consider making a small example (like the first line of Steven's code, below).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 1010:1239)
df$cut <- cut(df$V1, (max(df$V1) - min(df$V1) + 1) / 10, labels = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the `findInterval` function.

```
d <- data.frame(district = sample(1010:1239, 20))
d$label <- findInterval(d$district, 1000 + 10 * 1:24)
```

Feed it a vector to classify and a vector of break points, and it'll sort the first vector by the second. This can be particularly useful when combined with the `quantile` function, which returns a vector suitable for use in `findInterval` - but I think that's a little bit beyond what you want to do here.